# Java Script is not working in ubuntu firefox

Tags: javascript

My ASP application is running perfect in windows IE, but when i run on ubuntu firefox Javascript is not working properly..

Below is my java script code.....

And I am calling this java script on `onFocus` and `onBlur` event.
when `onBlur` is fired from date format 1 digit is removing in ubuntu firefox.

please somebody help.

```
function DateFormat(vDateName, vDateValue, e, dateCheck, dateType)  {

vDateType = dateType;

// vDateName = object name
// vDateValue = value in the field being checked
// e = event
// dateCheck 
//       True  = Verify that the vDateValue is a valid date
//       False = Format values being entered into vDateValue only
// vDateType
//       1 = mm/dd/yyyy
//       2 = yyyy/mm/dd
//       3 = dd/mm/yyyy


   //Enter a tilde sign for the first number and you can check the variable information.
   if (vDateValue == "~")
   {
      alert("AppVersion = "+navigator.appVersion+" \nNav. 4 Version = "+isNav4+" \nNav. 5 Version = "+isNav5+" \nIE Version = "+isIE4+" \nYear Type = "+vYearType+" \nDate Type = "+vDateType+" \nSeparator = "+strSeperator);
      vDateName.value = "";
      vDateName.focus();
      return true;
   }

   var whichCode = (window.Event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

   // Check to see if a seperator is already present.
   // bypass the date if a seperator is present and the length greater than 8
   if (vDateValue.length > 8 && isNav4)
   {
      if ((vDateValue.indexOf("-") >= 1) || (vDateValue.indexOf("/") >= 1))
         return true;
   }

   //Eliminate all the ASCII codes that are not valid
   var alphaCheck = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/-";
   if (alphaCheck.indexOf(vDateValue) >= 1)  
   {
      if (isNav4)
      {
         vDateName.value = "";
         vDateName.focus();
         vDateName.select();
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         vDateName.value = vDateName.value.substr(0, (vDateValue.length-1));
         return false;
      } 
   }
   if (whichCode == 8) //Ignore the Netscape value for backspace. IE has no value
      return false;
   else 
   {
      //Create numeric string values for 0123456789/
      //The codes provided include both keyboard and keypad values

      var strCheck = '47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105';
      if (strCheck.indexOf(whichCode) != -1)  
      {
         if (isNav4)  
         {
            if (((vDateValue.length =1))
            {
               alert("Invalid Date\nPlease Re-Enter");
               vDateName.value = "";
               vDateName.focus();
               vDateName.select();
               return false;
            }
            if (vDateValue.length == 6 && dateCheck)  
            {
               var mDay = vDateName.value.substr(2,2);
               var mMonth = vDateName.value.substr(0,2);
               var mYear = vDateName.value.substr(4,4)

               //Turn a two digit year into a 4 digit year
               if (mYear.length == 2 && vYearType == 4) 
               {
                  var mToday = new Date();

                  //If the year is greater than 30 years from now use 19, otherwise use 20
                  var checkYear = mToday.getFullYear() + 30; 
                  var mCheckYear = '20' + mYear;
                  if (mCheckYear >= checkYear)
                     mYear = '19' + mYear;
                  else
                     mYear = '20' + mYear;
               }
               var vDateValueCheck = mMonth+strSeperator+mDay+strSeperator+mYear;

               if (!dateValid(vDateValueCheck))  
               {
                  alert("Invalid Date\nPlease Re-Enter");
                  vDateName.value = "";
                  vDateName.focus();
                  vDateName.select();
                  return false;
                 }
               return true;

            }
            else
            {
               // Reformat the date for validation and set date type to a 1


               if (vDateValue.length >= 8  && dateCheck)  
               {
                  if (vDateType == 1) // mmddyyyy
                  {
                     var mDay = vDateName.value.substr(2,2);
                     var mMonth = vDateName.value.substr(0,2);
                     var mYear = vDateName.value.substr(4,4)
                     vDateName.value = mMonth+strSeperator+mDay+strSeperator+mYear;
                  }
                  if (vDateType == 2) // yyyymmdd
                  {
                     var mYear = vDateName.value.substr(0,4)
                     var mMonth = vDateName.value.substr(4,2);
                     var mDay = vDateName.value.substr(6,2);
                     vDateName.value = mYear+strSeperator+mMonth+strSeperator+mDay;
                  }
                  if (vDateType == 3) // ddmmyyyy
                  {
                     var mMonth = vDateName.value.substr(2,2);
                     var mDay = vDateName.value.substr(0,2);
                     var mYear = vDateName.value.substr(4,4)
                     vDateName.value = mDay+strSeperator+mMonth+strSeperator+mYear;
                  }

                  //Create a temporary variable for storing the DateType and change
                  //the DateType to a 1 for validation.

                  var vDateTypeTemp = vDateType;
                  vDateType = 1;
                  var vDateValueCheck = mMonth+strSeperator+mDay+strSeperator+mYear;

                  if (!dateValid(vDateValueCheck))  
                  {
                     alert("Invalid Date\nPlease Re-Enter");
                     vDateType = vDateTypeTemp;
                     vDateName.value = "";
                     vDateName.focus();
                     vDateName.select();
                     return false;
                    }
                     vDateType = vDateTypeTemp;
                     return true;
                }
               else
               {
                  if (((vDateValue.length =1))
                  {
                     alert("Invalid Date\nPlease Re-Enter");
                     vDateName.value = "";
                     vDateName.focus();
                     vDateName.select();
                     return false;
                  }
               }
            }
         }
         else  
         {
         // Non isNav Check
            if (((vDateValue.length =1))
            {
               alert("Invalid Date\nPlease Re-Enter");
               vDateName.value = "";
               vDateName.focus();
               return true;
            }

            // Reformat date to format that can be validated. mm/dd/yyyy


            if (vDateValue.length >= 8 && dateCheck)  
            {

               // Additional date formats can be entered here and parsed out to
               // a valid date format that the validation routine will recognize.

               if (vDateType == 1) // mm/dd/yyyy
               {
                  var mMonth = vDateName.value.substr(0,2);
                  var mDay = vDateName.value.substr(3,2);
                  var mYear = vDateName.value.substr(6,4)
               }
               if (vDateType == 2) // yyyy/mm/dd
               {
                  var mYear = vDateName.value.substr(0,4)
                  var mMonth = vDateName.value.substr(5,2);
                  var mDay = vDateName.value.substr(8,2);
               }
               if (vDateType == 3) // dd/mm/yyyy
               {
                  var mDay = vDateName.value.substr(0,2);
                  var mMonth = vDateName.value.substr(3,2);
                  var mYear = vDateName.value.substr(6,4)
               }
               if (vYearLength == 4)
               {
                  if (mYear.length = checkYear)
                     mYear = '19' + mYear;
                  else
                     mYear = '20' + mYear;
                  vDateValueCheck = mMonth+strSeperator+mDay+strSeperator+mYear;

                  // Store the new value back to the field.  This function will
                  // not work with date type of 2 since the year is entered first.

                  if (vDateTypeTemp == 1) // mm/dd/yyyy
                     vDateName.value = mMonth+strSeperator+mDay+strSeperator+mYear;
                  if (vDateTypeTemp == 3) // dd/mm/yyyy
                     vDateName.value = mDay+strSeperator+mMonth+strSeperator+mYear;

               } 


               if (!dateValid(vDateValueCheck))  
               {
                  alert("Invalid Date\nPlease Re-Enter");
                  vDateType = vDateTypeTemp;
                  vDateName.value = "";
                  vDateName.focus();
                  return true;
                 }
               vDateType = vDateTypeTemp;
               return true;

            }
            else
            {

               if (vDateType == 1)
               {
                  if (vDateValue.length == 2)  
                  {
                     vDateName.value = vDateValue+strSeperator;
                  }
                  if (vDateValue.length == 5)  
                  {
                     vDateName.value = vDateValue+strSeperator;
                  }
               }
               if (vDateType == 2)
               {
                  if (vDateValue.length == 4)  
                  {
                     vDateName.value = vDateValue+strSeperator;
                  }
                  if (vDateValue.length == 7)  
                  {
                     vDateName.value = vDateValue+strSeperator;
                  }
               } 
               if (vDateType == 3)
               {
                  if (vDateValue.length == 2)  
                  {
                     vDateName.value = vDateValue+strSeperator;
                  }
                  if (vDateValue.length == 5)  
                  {
                     vDateName.value = vDateValue+strSeperator;
                  }
               }
               return true;
            }
         }
         if (vDateValue.length == 10   && dateCheck)  
         {
            if (!dateValid(vDateName))  
            {
// Un-comment the next line of code for debugging the dateValid() function error messages
//               alert(err);  
               alert("Invalid Date\nPlease Re-Enter");
               vDateName.focus();
               vDateName.select();
             }
         }
         return false;
      }
      else  
      {
         // If the value is not in the string return the string minus the last
         // key entered.
         if (isNav4)
         {
            vDateName.value = "";
            vDateName.focus();
            vDateName.select();
            return false;
         }
         else
         {
            vDateName.value = vDateName.value.substr(0, (vDateValue.length-1));
            return false;
         }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is related to firefox instead, Did you try it in Windows with firefox?

Comment: If the code works when called from onFocus, but not when called from onBlur, it's more likely that the problem is in the calling context than in the function. Please provide us the code where you call that function.

Comment: Also, if this problem happens in windows Firefox, i.e. it's not related to Ubuntu extensions, you will likely get more and better answers is Stack Overflow (http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: This can be much simplified using regular expressions... User agent detection using `navigator.userAgent` is so 2000.

Comment: Hello Javier Ricvera, This is my code as below

Comment: Hello Javier Ricvera, This is my code as below  :  response.write("<input type=text size=10 maxlength=10 onFocus='javascript:vDateType=3' onKeyUp='DateFormat(this,this.value,event,false,3)' onBlur='DateFormat(this,this.value,event,true,3)' name=recdlocal"&(i)&" value ="&recdlocal(i)&">")

Comment: It looks to me that this whichcode check is failing in Firefox.

Comment: hello javier , this fiunction is calling from my Asp DateFormat(this,this.value,event,false,3) and and the date format script is already post here.... pls ...

Answer (score 1):

press CTRL+SHIFT+J on Firefox, for error console, then reload the page. See what errors that gives.